# EKCalendar has no member defaultCalendarForNewReminders

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I'm trying to access the default calendar for new reminders using:

```
EKCalendar.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
```

This function should return an optional EKCalendar ([doc page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507543-defaultcalendarfornewreminders))

But calling it like above results in the error message mentioned in the title (It isn't a member of EKCalendar).

What am I missing?

Comment: you need to create EKReminder object than use defaultCalendarForNewReminders()

Comment: how exactly do you mean to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Found it out, the docs are irritating. They are saying it's an instance method on EKCalendar, but in fact it's on EKEventStore. So right would be:

```
EKEventStore().defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
```